# Move table from one database to another in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How to move a table from one Database to another Database without using phpMyAdmin? It will be better if it is possible by PHP.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE ..` can be used to move tables from one database to another:

```
alter table my_old_db.mytable rename my_new_db.mytable
```

Warning: as you asked, **this is a move, not a copy** to the new database!

But you will keep table data (and not integrity constraints if they apply in your case)

Regarding php, php is able to run sql commands so it won't be a problem.

Comment: this produces an error: ERROR 1435 (HY000): Trigger in wrong schema

Comment: @lal_bosdi `If there are any triggers associated with a table which is moved to a different database using RENAME TABLE, then the statement fails with the error Trigger in wrong schema.

Foreign keys that point to the renamed table are not automatically updated. In such cases, you must drop and re-create the foreign keys in order for them to function properly.` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html You need export table to sql and import in new db. Or drop all triggers, move table and create needed triggers from backup sql code.

Comment: Wow! This command works instantly as compared to doing an `insert into`

Comment: Make sure you don't put table names in  **``** signs. It will cause "table doesn't exist" error. At least that what happened to me. :)

Answer (score 23):

**Entire Database (all tables):**

```
mysqldump -u root databasename > dump.sql
mysql -u root databasename < dump.sql
```

**One Table:**

```
mysqldump -u root -p yourpass dbname tablename | mysql -u root -p pass secondDB
```

**PHP:**

Run PHP **SELECT FROM SOURCE-DB**  **TABLE** and Run **INSERT INTO Table** IN **TARGET-DB**

Comment: Note: All the above commands do a copy instead of move.