# ODBC call failed on Export Microsoft Access to mysql database (Create command denied to user YOUR_USER@localhost for table Your_Table_name)

Tags: mysql, odbc, ms-access-2010

I want to export table from Ms Access 2010 to Mysql using MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver,
But shows this error :
[image: this error in Ms Access 2010]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using database software and has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

'sec_user'  user in  MySQL has 'USAGE' privileges.

I create another "user DSN" to connect a user with 'ALL PRIVILEGES' in MySQL and it works correctly.
Then move table from that database to my desire database like this:

```
alter table my_old_db.mytable rename my_new_db.mytable
```

for more information about Move table from one database to another in MySQL see this post
[Move table from one database to another in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15558461/move-table-from-one-database-to-another-in-mysql)